# Simulating a 2nd order filter provides a 1st order response

Tags: active-filter, multisim

I'm trying to design a filter with a bandwidth of 150Hz, center frequency of approx. 60Hz, with a roll-off of 40dB/decade. I am following the design of a 2nd order Multiple Feedback Band-Pass filter as discussed in page 315 and 316 of [this reference manual](https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf).

[image]

I am simulating the example 2nd order MFB Band-pass, using the values given.

[image]

Despite being a 2nd order filter (so the decade roll-off should be 40dB/decade), the simulated roll-off in Multisim, according to my understanding, is still 20dB/decade.

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure what I've misunderstood in terms of core filter concepts, or simulation software. I'm assuming the documentation I've read is correct, so please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Your response starts at +20 dB/decade and becomes -20 dB/decade.  That's a change of -40dB/decade...  Presented differently, your "second-order" bandpass filter has one pole of lowpass (because the other is highpass).  To achieve 40dB/decade rolloff, you need two of each, for a total of 4th order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A 2nd order **low**-pass filter has a roll-off above the cut-off frequency of 40 dB/decade
- A 2nd order **high**-pass filter has a roll-off below the cut-off frequency of 40 dB/decade
- A 2nd order **band**-pass filter has a roll-off above and below the cut-off frequencies of **20 dB/decade**

Also, you can't use a simple 2nd order filter to achieve grossly asymmetrical cut-off frequencies as implied by this statement: -

> *I'm trying to design a filter with a bandwidth of 150Hz, center
> frequency of approx. 60Hz*

The above means a lower cut-off of 21 Hz and, an upper cut-off of 171 Hz = not possible with a single 2nd order filter.

Comment: "Also, you can't use a simple 2nd order filter to achieve grossly asymmetrical cut-off frequencies", can you elaborate on this statement?

Comment: The asymmetry I refer to is that 21 Hz is so much more massively closer to DC compared to 171 Hz.